# How can I add two logins in one web application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm working on a web application with [Spring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_Framework). It should be able to access by any user and administrator. User login is already implemented with Spring Security.

**web-security.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

    <!-- Enables Spring Security debugging infrastructure, and should only be
        used in a DEVELOPMENT environment -->
    <!-- <debug /> -->

    <http pattern="/static/**" security="none" />

    <http use-expressions="true" >

        <!-- Setting user permissions here -->

        <intercept-url pattern="/login*" access="permitAll" />


        <!--Setting user permissions here -->



        <!--End Setting user permissions here -->

        <form-login login-page="/timeres_login"
            authentication-failure-url="/timeres_login?login_error=1"
            default-target-url="/userlogin"  />

        <logout logout-url="/logout"
        logout-success-url="/home"
            delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" invalidate-session="true" />
        <access-denied-handler error-page="/accessDenied" />

        <custom-filter position="CONCURRENT_SESSION_FILTER" ref="concurrencyFilter" />

         <session-management invalid-session-url="/home?error=sessionExpired"
            session-authentication-strategy-ref="sas"
            session-authentication-error-url="/timeres_login?error=alreadyLogin">
        </session-management>
    </http>

    <beans:bean id="concurrencyFilter"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter">
        <beans:property name="sessionRegistry" ref="sessionRegistry" />
        <beans:property name="expiredUrl" value="/session-expired" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="sas"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy">
        <beans:constructor-arg name="sessionRegistry"
            ref="sessionRegistry" />
        <beans:property name="maximumSessions" value="1" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="sessionRegistry"
        class="org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl" />

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider ref="daoAuthenticationProvider" />
    </authentication-manager>

    <beans:bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider"
        class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
        <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService" />
        <!-- <beans:property name="passwordEncoder" ref="passwordEncoder" /> -->
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="userDetailsService"
        class="com.timeres.security.AuthenticationUserDetailService">
    </beans:bean>

<!--     <beans:bean id="passwordEncoder" -->
<!--         class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.ShaPasswordEncoder"> -->
<!--         <beans:constructor-arg index="0" value="256" /> -->
<!--     </beans:bean> -->

</beans:beans>
```

And now I want to add the administrator login part.

First I want to know whether it is able to add two different logins in one web application.
If it is able to do, how?
(Where should I change and what are the classes I should implement?)

Comment: after login -> if user == admin -> go to admin page else if user == normalIUser --> go to main page --> else go to error page

Comment: when doing like that both admin and user login with same page isn't  it ?

Comment: not necessarily. You can have two pages pointing to the same business logic

Comment: then I want to add another <form-login /> to xml file.But it doesn't work.

Comment: 'but it doesn't work'. that's pretty vague

Comment: Why can't you have the same login page for both user? Its just a login page. The details/secured page should come only after login. If you can't detect a user role with user id, then provide a drop down as well, along with userid/password to let user specify admin or normal user

Comment: I tried with that, when I change the <form login login-page="/admin_login"/> and but still it works only for timeres_login.Do I want to change any where other

Comment: yes if I use same login page it can be done.But I want to know the way that use two login pages.